# C homework, ignore for now (I think I am going repost later with some code)

Tags: c, error-handling

I am going to be making a program that reads in a line and gets up to 6 numbers.  The program will eventually solve a a square matrix between 2x2 and 6x6.  My question is what errors do I need to look for on the get_numb() function?

I am thinking that the function will have to check character by character to make sure that the individual characters are actual numbers and not a EOF or \n.  I will have to also check that there is not more than 6 numbers on a line.  I am about a week into programing, so is there anything I need to know to tackle this?

Comment: You didn't say what the `get_numb()` function is supposed to do, so it's difficult to try and help you determine what errors you might need to look for. Is this a function that parses an input line and returns an array of numbers, for example? You will need to be more clear.

Comment: It is very important that you sort this out for yourself and make all the classic mistakes that new programmers make.  Us giving you advice so that you avoid these mistakes would be a great disservice to you.

Comment: @Hans, I slightly disagree. Basically the OP asks for advice on what use cases to cover / what to test. When you don't know what you don't know, it is almost impossible for you to realize that without external feedback. The feedback may indeed be a real-life test of the program created, but it may also simply be advice for what cases to unit test in advance. I do believe the latter can be a useful learning experience, even if the former is more dramatic.

Comment: @KevenK get_num function will take in up to 6 numbers and basically thats it, but it needs to do it right, with error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely recommend you start by taking into use a good unit testing framework, and write unit tests as you go. This way you can cover all the cases you mention above, and make sure that your program really works the way you think it should work.

There are loads of [questions on SO about C unit testing frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+[unit-testing]+framework); pick your favourite.

Apart from the cases you mention, I can think of the following:

- less than 6 numbers on a line
- empty line
- (if the numbers are floating point, various number formats)

If your teacher gave you sample input / output, you may of course incorporate that into your unit tests as well.

Comment: Unit testing for a 2 week old C coder?  This person probably just wrote hello world.  Are you sure you want to go here already?

Comment: @Michael, I think the earlier you start, the better :-) And since the OP seems to be actively thinking about use cases to cover, it occurred to me unit testing may be a good fit for him/her. Should there be a problem, there are lots of people here on SO to help, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @Micheal I did, I wrote the hello world code,  but I have no choice we were given this assignment, and I have a week to do it.  That's why I was brainstorming.

Answer (score 1):

The potential errors you described are reasonable ones to check for.

I recommend you give it a shot.  If they're not sufficient and you get stuck, then post your code and explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Post it assuming you're allowed to by your instructor, of course. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most ascii to integer converters will help you out with the error checking.  Here's hoping your teacher gave you some example input code and perhaps, depending on the input methods, some example conversion code.  As this is homework, I don't want to get too specific.